# Image appearing on the screen, but not moving with key events

Tags: python, pygame

The image is appearing on the screen, but I cannot move it with the w, s, a, d keys in my program.  How do I fix this?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
spriteLoc = ('sprite.png')
#backgroundLoc = ('background.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.key.set_repeat(30,30)
pygame.display.set_caption('Focus.')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
sprite = pygame.image.load(spriteLoc).convert_alpha()
#background = pygame.image.load(backgroundLoc).convert_alpha()
#bgx,bgy = (0,0)

class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = image
#        self.posx = posx
#        self.posy = posy

    def playerEvents(self):
        global posx
        global posy
        posx = 0
        posy = 0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key == K_w:
                posy -= 5
            elif pygame.key == K_s:
                posy += 5
            elif pygame.key == K_a:
                posx -= 5
            elif pygame.key == K_d:
                posx += 5
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if pygame.key == K_w:
                posy = 0
            elif pygame.key == K_s:
                posy = 0
            elif pygame.key == K_a:
                posx = 0
            elif pygame.key == K_d:
                posx = 0

        self.x = self.x + posx
        self.y = self.y + posy

        #screen.blit(background,(bgx,bgy))
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))

me = Player(50,50,sprite)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        screen.fill(black)

        me.playerEvents()
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

When I made the posx and posy globals positive and either pressed any key or moved the mouse over the window, the sprite moved down-right. Making them negative moved them in the opposite direction. As you can see by the code that's commented out, I tried to use a background image to see if that made a difference. I've searched, researched, commented out possible problem areas, and rearranged everything. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried event.key rather than pygame.key

Comment: Let me know if that works and I'll submit as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `pygame.key` to `event.key` in your `playerEvents` method.